# JQuery Ajax, Can I use the id from a tag as variable in ajax-call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dynamicaly generated webpage where I would like to use Ajax-calls to insert additional data on request (clicks) by the user.

In the sample code below I try to show what I need. When the user clicks on either John's or Anne's lines, an Ajax-call should be made returning the correct city. I would like to use the "id" attribute as a parameter in the call, but I don't understand how I can retreive the correct attribute...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickable").click(function(){
        $("#city").load("get_city_for.php?name=[the_name_from_id_in_the_clicked_div] ");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="clickable" id="John">Click here to show where John lives<div>
<div class="clickable" id="Anne">Click here to show where Anne lives<div>

<div id="city">(click above to show the city here)</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So when the user clicks on John's line the Jquery code should call "get_city_for.php?name=John", since the id attribute of John's line is "John".

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickable").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
        $("#city").load("get_city_for.php?.php?name="+$(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="clickable" id="John">Click here to show where John lives<div>
<div class="clickable" id="Anne">Click here to show where Anne lives<div>

<div id="city">(click above to show the city here)</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Use `$(this).attr("id")`. The `attr` function is used for accessing attributes from DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

In `.click()`, `this` will be the element you clicked, so and you can use `$(this).attr("id")` to get the id of the clicked element. `.attr("someatribute")` returns the atribute value of the element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clickable").click(function(){
        $("#city").load("get_city_for.php?name=" + $(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        const $document = $(document);

        $document.ready(function() {
            $document.find('.clickable').on('click', (e) => {
                const urlRequest = `get_city_for.php?name=${e.target.id}`;

                $document.find('#city').load(urlRequest);

                console.log(urlRequest);
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="clickable" id="John">Click here to show where John lives<div>
<div class="clickable" id="Anne">Click here to show where Anne lives<div>

<div id="city">(click above to show the city here)</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why to use .find() here? when you can dirctly access dom object thorugh ID or class name. QuerySelector is an other option too

Comment: You caching document selector first of all.